# Which version of iWork can I use on OS X 10.6.3?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, iwork

I have OS X 10.6.3 installed on my iMac.

I would like to download a trial version of iWork but the latest version (9.1) is not compatible with my OS X version.

Which is the right version of iWork for me and where could I download the trial version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Apple's [iWork system requirements](http://www.apple.com/iwork/systemrequirements.html) page, you should be able to download [this trial version](http://www.apple.com/iwork/download-trial/).